# Android Drag to Bottom of Screen to Remove

Tags: android, drag, dismiss

I have been googling and also searching Stackoverflow for some hints on how to Drag something to the bottom of the screen to remove. Seems Very simple and Strait forward but I can not find and documentation or examples. Many Apps use this including Android itself being able to drag a home screen icon to the top to remove. Apps like Facebook use it to drag the ChatHead to the bottom of the screen to remove. 
Can anybody Post links to documention, examples or such as a place to start? or provide examples